# NSSearchField: how long is the search delay? Is it configurable?

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nssearchfield

NSSearchField allows you to uncheck "search immediately" in the Interace Builder attributes editor. When this is the case, the target action will not be invoked until a short time after the user stops typing.

1. Exactly how long is this delay?
2. Is this delay configurable? If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the delay is configurable. What you could do is set the text field to search immediately but then override `-textDidChange:` in a subclass of `NSSearchFieldCell`.

You could then control the search delay using an `NSTimer` or some other method and call super's implementation of `-textDidChange:` when you want to trigger the search.

Comment: good calls on how to reimplement this by hand using a custom delay interval. i'm still curious about part 1 of my question for educational reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately, since the delay value is not public there's no easy way to find out the exact interval that I can see.